Building a large constant current driver from small ones
If you had some constant current drivers and you connected them (in parallel), would they all act as a single large driver? For example, if you had 5 constant current drivers that could output up to 10A each, could you join them together to essentially make a driver that had an amp output of up to 50A?

Depends on how they are implemented. How’s yours?

What does "driver" mean in this case, are they not just ideal current sources? In what way(s) are they non-ideal? Perhaps some of those ways conflict.

I have actually done this, but with lower current, LED drivers.
I needed about 600-900 mA for my LED string running at around 55-60 V, so I used two 300 mA drivers whose output voltage range was from below 50 V to about 72 V, and it ran just fine.
The current was doubled and the voltage slightly raised.
As long as your load keeps the drivers within their output voltage range, it should work without problems.
Just pay attention to other issues related to large currents, like voltage drops across wires, overheating of the wires and joints/contacts.
